# Statistically support a conclusion of time series

Tags: r, time-series

I'm currently submitting a paper about elements in soil solution. Reviewers told me to justify the conclusion by the data, and I need some of your unlimited knowledge.

Here is a plot of $\textrm{Al }$ present in soil solution over $6$ years. My conclusion to be supported is that during winter (trees dormancy, the purple line is $21~\rm  Dec. $ of each year), more $\rm Al$ is released in solution.

[image]

My initial intuition is to support it using time series analysis. However, despite knowing some stuff about statistics, I never did time series analysis.

So, here are my questions:

- Is my analysis relevant given my conclusion to be supported?
- How in R, analyze using the `forecast` library? I already did :

`sarima_model <- auto.arima(soil_data, seasonal = TRUE)`

`summary(sarima_model)` which gives me :

```
Series: tsdata 
ARIMA(0,0,2) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ma1     ma2    mean
      0.3591  0.3215  0.1127
s.e.  0.0569  0.0564  0.0119

sigma^2 estimated as 0.01387:  log likelihood=197.92
AIC=-387.84   AICc=-387.69   BIC=-373.4

Training set error measures:
                        ME      RMSE        MAE      MPE     MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set -0.0001118715 0.1171314 0.07782753 768.5151 1255.721 0.9025749 0.02918578
```

But I am not able to interpret
results.

Comment: Why can't you just compare the quantity of interest for winter vs not if that is your hypothesis?

Comment: Well, that is a way to do it ? I was just wondering what 'the right way' was to do it

Comment: There's no single "right" way. But if your question is if there is a different between winter vs not, then saying that there is some seasonality does not answer it.

Comment: Thanks. Time series dosnt seem to be it then

Comment: As I said, there are many possible solutions, treating it as a time-series is one of them.

Comment: What do you think would be a good manner to do it then ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't get any answer yet, let me give you a short one.

First, there is no single solution. There are many different possible approaches. Choosing between them would boil down to the details like what exactly is your research question and what is your data.

Second, you say

> My conclusion to be supported is that during winter (trees dormancy, the purple line is $21~\rm  Dec. $ of each year), more $\rm Al$ is released in solution. [...]

That's not a great start. You should start with forming a hypothesis and then validating it with data. If your aim is only to find something that would confirm the conclusion you already formed, it's not a good reason to use statistics, as it will be very susceptible to cherry-picking ("this didn't confirm my conclusion, let's try something else").

But let's say that your hypothesis is "there is a difference in $\rm Al$ levels between winter and other seasons". In such a case, to *directly* verify the hypothesis, you can simply divide the data into two groups "winter" and "not winter" and compare the levels using some statistical test (e.g. $t$-test).

On another hand, if the question is broader "if there is a seasonality...", then, using time-series analysis makes sense. It also is something you would pick if there is a dependence over time in the levels of $\rm Al$, so ignoring it would be incorrect.

Finally, if your aim is not forecasting, but you want to test a hypothesis, you probably should not use things like `auto.arima`, but rather come up with a simple, easily interpretable model, that makes sense for your data, and go with it. But I'll leave you here, as this is not my main area of expertise.

Comment: Yes, i'm aware that i taking this in reverse, but conclusion support is needed. Thanks for that long answer